# Copying all symbology of layer through Apply Symbology From Layer using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, symbology

I wanted to copy the symbology from a previous layer in Arcpy, and it effectively works through the following function:

```
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management
```

However, it only copies one point type ("result") in the place of all three ("layer_symbology"), since the first layer in its attributes has only one of the three.

[image]

Is there an option of this function so that it copies exactly the symbology of the layer "layer_symbology" through the aforementioned function despite not having the other attributes in its attributes?

If necessary I can copy the script.

Comment: You need to provide your exact usage, or a similar usage that results in the same results. I use a layer file to apply symbology with ArcPy to a graduated colors layer all the time, and it works just fine.

Comment: I don't think what you are asking is possible. You can't symbolize on something that doesn't exist. You might need a workaround. Use arcpy to copy the layer_symbology layer, then rename to result, then change the source to the source featureclass/shape/whatever for result. That way Adults in orchards/Adults in others will be there, but when you change the source back to 'result', they will show as having 0 count.

Comment: As timlohnes says, apparently you can't. My solution was to set the legend as "graphic", so even though the symbology is modified, the legend does not.